# Triple Integral of $\iiint \frac{ 1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)} dxdydz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate this triple integral of$$\iiint \frac{ 1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2+1)} dx dy dz$$? Does it converge?

Comment: What is the domain of the integral?

Comment: Generaly i would switch to spherical coordinates. What are the bounds of the integral, is it over whole R

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If the region is spherical use [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to solve the integral.

$$dV = dx\,dy\, dz = r^2\sin \theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d \varphi$$

The integral will be reduced to

$$\int_D \dfrac{r^2}{r^2 + 1}\sin\theta \,dr \,d\theta \,d\varphi.$$